# ggplot boxplots with 2 y axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have been looking everywhere to find out how to ggplot boxplots with 2 y axes.

This is what I want the plot to look like:

[boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqtOj.png)

Example data:

```
Sample  Tumor   Score_1 Score_2
1       A       100     -20
2       B       80      -10
3       C       5       -5
4       C       6       -7
5       C       80      -8
6       C       70      -30
7       C       80      -5
8       C       90      -6
9       A       150     -8
10      B       1       -10
11      B       2       -10
12      B       4       -9
13      B       5       -7
14      B       8       -6
15      B       10      -4
16      B       12      -8
17      B       7       -10
18      B       6       -11
19      C       70      -15
20      C       90      -4
21      C       95      -3
22      C       120     -6
23      C       130     -9
24      C       50      -5
25      C       113     -10
26      C       100     -2
27      C       90      -1
28      C       50      -11
29      C       80      -15
30      A       200     -7
31      A       200     -4
32      A       180     -3
33      A       160     -9
34      A       107     -15
35      A       115     -11
36      A       80      -12
37      A       90      -14
38      A       130     -13
39      A       140     -9
40      A       120     -10
```

```
myboxplot <- read.csv("Example.csv")

#Set up labels
ylim.prim <- c(0, 500)   
ylim.sec <- c(-35, 0)

b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- b*(ylim.prim[1] - ylim.sec[1])

myboxplot %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Score_1, Score_2)) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("Score_1", "Score_2"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Tumor)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = value, fill = name)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name ="Score 1", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ((. - a)/b), name = expression("Score 2"))) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Tumor") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        text = element_text(size = 12),
        #axis.title = element_text(face="bold"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size = 11),
        legend.position = "right") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("GrandBudapest2"))
```

I do get the plot in the image (linked above), the problem is my second set of data (the purple boxplots "Score 2") is not being aligned with the second y axis, it is aligning with the first y axis. Since the data is much smaller with a range of -35 to 0, you can't see the difference between the tumor types. Does anyone have any ideas how to change this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Haha, your problem is perfect evidence for why I hate ggplot2. Just use base plot. `boxplot()` followed by `axis(4,...)`. Problem solved. Instead, you just wrote like 12 lines of ggplot code and it still doesn't work... cause ggplot2 is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the plot you are requesting might be misleading. Instead, how about a facet?

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c("Sample","Tumor"), names_to = "Score") %>%
ggplot(aes( x= Tumor, y = value, fill = Score)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(.~Score, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Or as @NickCox suggests:

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c("Sample","Tumor"), names_to = "Score") %>%
  group_by(Score,Tumor) %>%
  arrange(value) %>%
  mutate(xcoord = seq(-0.25,0.25,length.out = n()),
         Tumor = factor(Tumor)) %>%
ggplot(aes( x= Tumor, y = value, fill = Score)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, coef = 0) +
  geom_point(aes(x = xcoord + as.integer(Tumor))) +
  facet_wrap(.~Score, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: That would be my main comment too. A different comment is that the original data are often rounded in a way that box plots can't do justice to. Perhaps the rounding is just a matter of measurement or reporting conventions or of avoiding spurious precision, but the reader should be allowed to see it.

Comment: Your extra code doesn't quite do quantile-box in Parzen's style. The horizontal extent of each box in principle covers 50% of the range.  Hence the quartiles are, or should be, plotted at top right and bottom left corners of the box. There is small print about details. But for interpretation. your design and mine are in practice similar enough for most purposes, or so I suggest.

Comment: Thanks so much @Ian, I ended up just using facet_wrap

Answer (score 0):

[This was posted when the question was on Cross Validated]

Box plots I find oversold whenever, as usually, there is scope to show more detail. Here is one of several possibilities, a quantile-box plot in Parzen's sense in which for each group a standard box showing median and quartiles is superimposed on a quantile plot, in which the implicit horizontal axis is rank order. The detail that apart from some small integers many values are just multiples of 10 is of interest and should help a little in interpretation.

[image]

This plot doesn't use R. People who use R should find doing something similar or better to be trivial -- and those whose favourite software is different should be able to say the same. If not, you need new favourite software.